# Regex for matching a name followed by numbers

Tags: regex

The problem i have with this task is:

- If there is a `:` or `/` between the name and the number there **CAN** be a whitespace bevore and after the symbol
- If there is non of the symbols there **MUST** be a whitespace between the name and the number.

So far i came to this:

```
^\s*[^/:\d]*\s*?[/:]?\s*([0-9]{6,10})\s*$
```

But that matches `Name1234567` wrong. It should be wrong but is true. (there MUST be a whitespace between)

`1234567`, `Name 1234567` or `Name/1234567` works everything perfectly fine. But i can't get that one specific task working.

Hope someone can fix that problem. 
Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
[a-zA-Z]*(?:\s|(?:\s?[:\/]\s?))\d+
```

for example http://regex101.com/r/dD3lP4/1

**How it matches**

`[a-zA-Z]*` matches any number of alphabets

`(?:\s|(?:\s?[:\/]\s?))`matches a space `\s` or `\s?[:\/]\s?` space followed by `:` or `/` again followed by space \s. The quantifies `?` makes `\s` occurence as zero or one (can part in the question)

`\d+` matches any number of digits